# grep search in R

Tags: r

I have the attached the image of the table and I want to filter the column 'title' based on the below search criteria.Title column contains text.

`word=c('COVID','coronavirus disease 19','SARS-CoV-2','2019-nCoV','nCoV','coronavirus','wuhan pneumonia','Wuhan')`

for searching a word I know I  can use

`merged[grep("COVID",merged$Title),"Title"]`
or

`sapply(words, grepl, merged$Title)  returns TRUE and FALSE. How to select the rows for which sapply is true.`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OnuP.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

We can use `lapply` and `Reduce` it to a single logical `vector` with `|` to subset the rows of 'merged' i.e. we are selecting the rows of the 'merged', when any of the 'words' are present in the 'Title' column

```
merged[Reduce(`|`, lapply(words, grepl, merged$Title)),]
```

---

Another option is to `paste` it to a single string with `|` as the separator which will acts like `OR`

```
pat <- paste0("\\b(", paste(words, collapse="|"), ")\\b")
merged[grepl(pat, merged$Title),]
```